# Find if data-set contains any data for the last 2 days using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am making call to the database and getting some data about the user.  If the dataset does not contain any data for the last 2 days, I simply want to redirect the user to another page.   The data would look like something like this:

```
UserID               DateSubmitted
User1               2015-03-13 00:00:00.000
User1               2015-03-15 00:00:00.000
User1               2015-03-16 00:00:00.000
```

So if user did not make any submission for the last 2 days; I want to redirect the user to another page.  In this case, we see the user did submit on 3/13, 3/15  and 3/16 but failed to submit on 3/14 so I want to redirect him to another page.  Here is what i have done so far but could not completed...

```
 string tempUser = (string)Session["USRID"];
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select UserID, DateSubmitted from myTable where userid = @userid ", sqlcon);
            DataTable dtSETS = new DataTable();
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userid", (tempUser));
            da.Fill(dtSETS);

            if (dtSETS.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow dtSETS_row = dtSETS.Rows[0];


                 //i want to do the checking here..
                 if(some condition here)
                   {

                   }

             }
```

Comment: I would add the date check to the WHERE in SQL.

Comment: My initial thought is to agree with Al Kepp.  However, since the user has data for 3/16, it seems to me that the user does, in fact, have some data for the last two days.  Not *both* days, but one of them.  That makes me wonder if there might be a miscommunication about your requirements going on.  Can you elaborate on why User1 should fail your validation?

Comment: the requirement is for the last 2 days but not today (3/16).  the data for 3/14 is missing in my example, hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this SQL Query will do the work for you.  (By having your SQL Server do the work, there should be less data returned to your client application and performance should be better.)

```
DECLARE @MyTable table (UserID varchar(50), DateSubmitted datetime);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 'User1', '3/13/2015');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 'User1', '3/15/2015');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 'User1', '3/16/2015');
--INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 'User1', '3/14/2015');

SELECT UserID, DateSubmitted 
FROM @MyTable 
WHERE userid = 'User1' 
AND DATEDIFF(day, DateSubmitted, GETDATE()) = 0 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM @MyTable 
     WHERE UserID = 'User1' 
     AND DATEDIFF(day, DateSubmitted, GETDATE()) IN (1,2)) < 2;
```